# Swift 3 Use Subtitle Style Cell in TableView Programatically

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I have a table based app in which I would like to use a .subtitle style cell.  I am using the following code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Dequeue Resuable Cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellIdentifier) ?? UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier)


        cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Goodbye"

        return cell
    }
```

But I do not think this is actually setting my cells to subtitle style since the app looks like the following when launched:

[image]

Also noteworthy is that I am not using a "Prototype" cell in the Storyboard (the tutorial I started with eschewed them) so I cannot set the cell style there, it needs to be in code.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What type of cell are you using? Custom Cell? And I wonder how! Are you using storyboard? Your code seems like you are using `UITableViewCell`

Comment: I am not using a custom cell, I am using the default UITableViewCell.  The storyboard contains the TableViewControllers and the NavigationController only.

Comment: Okay then. You have to select the `Cell` in the storyboard and then from _Attributes Inspector_ you have to select `Subtitle` style.

Comment: Ah, but there is the rub.  The cell does not exist in the storyboard.  Only the TableViewControllers and the NavigationController.

Comment: If your TableViewController does exist, the `Cell` must be exist. See my answer below to visualize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using Table View Controller in the storyboard. Then you are using `Prototype` cell obviously. You have to explicitly set the cell style to `Subtitle` in the *Attributes Inspector* for the table view cell.

[image: Setting style for prototype cell of table view]

Comment: Actually, the tutorial I followed included deleting the Prototype Cell from the storyboard as one of its steps.  This is why I need to set the style in code!  I tried adding the prototype cell back into the storyboard and setting the style there but it had no effect.

Comment: Can you try like this: _Delete the entire Table View Controller from storyboard -> Drag and Drop a Table View Controller from object library -> Select the table view cell -> Set style_?

Comment: I have done something similar: I incremented the Prototype Cell from 0 to 1 (thus adding it back), and then setting the style as you suggested.  Is this the same thing?  Or do you believe deleting and recreating the entire TVC will do something different?

Comment: The way you followed, I just tried that out and it's working perfectly for my case. Maybe you have some other issues! Maybe with `Identifier` property. Try different identifier for deque and initialization with `UITableViewCell(style:reuseIdentifier:)`. Or you can have a look at [my demo project](https://bitbucket.org/m-i-n/prototype-cell-demo/overview)

Comment: As an update, I did completely delete the TVC from the storyboard and then re-add one, leaving the Prototype cell intact.  I set the reuse identifier to match the code and set the style to Subtitle, but the detail text is not showing.  This is very frustrating.

Comment: Awesome.  Got it working, thanks to your demo app.  One thing I do not understand: In this line, why are the cell reuse identifiers different? let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PrototypeCell") ?? UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

Comment: I wish I could give your answer more than one upvotes!